# How can I add more than one label in the same cell of a TableLayout in windows forms?

Tags: windows, winforms, forms, tablelayout

How can I add more than one label in the same cell of a TableLayoutPanel in windows forms ?

Comment: You can't.  Adjust the layout to fake it, or embed another TLP in that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Only one control can be added to each pane in the TableLayoutPanel, but that control can be another container control, like panel. Dock the panel in each pane to DockStyle.Fill, then any number of labels can be added to the panel inside the pane.